# Is there any sample solution about bitbucket pull request(not cloud) which is triggering sonarcube analyze on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, bitbucket

we would like to start a sonarqube analyze on  developers' branches (bitbucket) just before pull requests via jenkins . Is there a sample solution?as far as i understood  "sonar for bitbucketserver" plugin only shows the analysis results it does not trigger sonarqube analysis . Our scanner will be on jenkins

Comment: If I understand correctly, by "sample solution" you mean "[Please code this for me](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)"

Comment: In fact i wanted to ask if there is a bitbucket plugin to start sonar cube analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without a CI tool I was able to trigger analysis by adding the plugin sonar-stash to sonarqube. This way integrating with Bitbucket. Command I executed in sonarqube server, under sonar-scanner/bin folder:

```
./sonar-scanner -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview 
-Dsonar.stash.notification=true 
-Dsonar.stash.project=JAVA 
-Dsonar.stash.repository=abcd
-Dsonar.stash.pullrequest.id=2 
-Dsonar.stash.password=**********
```